# Helmet Content Security Policy blocking React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, single-page-application, helmet.js

I am currently developing an SPA using react. In order to serve the SPA I simply have an express server which serves the build folder as a static folder.

But whenever I try to run the application nothing loads and I get the console error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-1kri9uKG6Gd9VbixGzyFE/kaQIHihYFdxFKKhgz3b80='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

I've done a lot of googling but I can't find anything that works.

I've tried disabling helmets CSP but I still get the error.

I've tried uninstalling helmet, nothing.

Stopping and restarting the server, nope.

stopping everything, restarting the server and reopening chrome, nope.

Currently this is my use statement

```
App.use(helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
            defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
            scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", 'https://ajax.googleapis.com', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com'],
            styleSrc: ["'self'"],
            imgSrc: ["*", 'data:'],
            connectSrc: ["'self'"],
            frameSrc: ["'self'"],
        },
    }
}));
```

because it's the same error no matter what I'm assuming the CSP isn't updating but I don't know enough to test this theory or what I could even do to remedy it.

Comment: Can you post your local url to load frontend on the browser, and the url to make request to your express server? I think both are running on different servers. Basically, when you load any website, the very first network call made remains responsible for CSP issue.

Comment: @RinkalRohara for the frontend its localhost:3000 which works fine and I can make API calls from there to the backend but if I try to access the app through localhost:5000 which the backend serves it serves the index.html file but the react code doesn't load and that error shows in the terminal

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. At a glance, your Helmet CSP configuration looks correct, but it seems like the header isn't being updated. You can check the header by going to the Network tab in your browser's devtools. What is the value of the Content-Security-Policy header? Does it match your Helmet configuration? Is something caching an old header? Have you tried completely restarting everything and clearing all caches?

Comment: ok refreshing and clearing cache worked thank you so much I feel kinda stupid for not trying that it's one of the simplest solutions to any kind of persistent problem. @EvanHahn. also kinda unrelated but it's kind of amazing helmet maintainers will just straight up try to fix any problem marked with the helmet tag, thank you for your service

Comment: Of course. (By the way: the "helmet maintainers" is just one person, me! It's a pretty small package so it's not too much work. Feel free to reach out if you have any other Helmet questions.)

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comment from the helmet maintainer Evan Hahn, I did a little googling to remember the shortcut then just went to the site and hit ctrl-F5 to refresh the page and clear the cache at the same time, worked like a charm.